# Correlation coefficient and non linear association

Tags: regression, pearsons-correlation-coefficient

Correlation and Linear Regression

Author:

Lisa Sullivan, PhD

Professor of Biostatistics

Boston University School of Public Health

Says there  may be non-linear association which the correlation  coefficient does not detect. I disagree with this idea. The Karl Pearson correlation coefficient actually computes the degree of relative changes in two variables which may be constant or varying.

Comment: What's the question is?

Comment: Question  : do you agree with the assertion that the correlation coefficient doesn't assess  nonlinear association,  if any. As I understand  the Karl Pearson  r formula determines the relationship between random variations between  two variables and by  ignoring fixed consistent relationship,  it is based on so called  non-linear  association.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Dr. Sullivan is right. For example, take a perfect quadratic relationship between X and Y.

Here is some Python code to show nine sample points and calculate their Pearson correlation coefficient. You can skip the code and just look at the results below if you trust me.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn')
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [5, 8]

x = np.arange(-4, 5)
y = x**2  # This is x squared. 

plt.scatter(x, y)

plt.axis('equal')
plt.title('$X = Y^2$', fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('X', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Y', fontsize=14, rotation=0)
plt.xticks([-4, -2, 0, 2, 4])
plt.yticks([0, 1, 4, 9, 16])

# Calculate the Pearson correlation coefficient:
print('r =', np.corrcoef(x, y)[0, 1])
```

**r = 0.0**

[image: X-Y scatterplot]

Surely there is a relation between X and Y in this example, and yet the Pearson correlation coefficient is zero.

Comment: Please indicate the presumed quadratic equation. Am not a software fellow.

Comment: Just $Y = X^2$.

Comment: I improved the plot above to make the quadratic function more obvious.

Comment: I think that population correlation (rho) is assumed to be zero when sample correlation (r) is calculated. You have denoted it as r = 0 for the plot. I am trying  to say correlation measures the relationship  between  two variables which denotes either the positive or negative    relation or neither.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You can always calculate $r$, without making any assumptions about $\rho$. Perhaps you are thinking of a hypothesis test, with $\rho = 0$ being the null hypothesis. But the $r = 0$ above would be a purely empirical, descriptive way to quantify the relationship between $X$ and $Y$ in the sample, albeit not a very good one, as the plot shows.

Comment: can X take positive as well as negative values? what is the assumption? What  is the scale type ?

Comment: Yes, X can take positive or negative values. The assumption is just that there is a perfect quadratic relationship between Y and X. As for the scale type, X may be any real number.